# Can I install Ubuntu on blackberry passport?

Tags: blackberry

Can I install Ubuntu on a blackberry passport?

Comment: I've done some research and it seems like the BlackBerry has a locked and signed bootloader. You probably won't be able to install Ubuntu on it.